# Converting time to hexidecimal then to string using javascrit

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert present time to hexidecimal then to a regular string variable.
For some reason I can only seem to produce an output in double quotes such as "result" or an object output. I am using Id tags to identify each div which contains different messages. They are being used like this id="somename-hexnumber". The code if sent from the browser to a node.js server and the ID is split up into two words with first section being the person's name then "-" is the split key then the hexidecimal is just the div number so it is easy to find and delete if needed. The code I got so far is small but I am out of ideas now.

```
var thisRandom = Date.now();
const encodedString = thisRandom.toString(16);
var encoded = JSON.stringify(encodedString); 
var tIDs = json.name+'-'+encoded;
var output = $('<div class="container" id="'+tIDs+'" onclick="DelComment(this.id, urank)"><span class="block"><div class="block-text"><p><strong>&lt;'+json.name+'&gt;</strong> '+json.data+'</p></div></div>');
```

When a hexidecimal number is produced I want the output to be something like 16FE67A334 and not "16FE67A334" or an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do you want this ?**

Demo: https://codepen.io/gmkhussain/pen/QWEdOBW

Code below will convert the time/number value d to hexadecimal.

```js
var thisRandom = Date.now();

function timeToHexFunc(x) {
   if ( x < 0) {
     x = 0xFFFFFFFF + x + 1;
   }
  return x.toString(16).toUpperCase();
}

console.log(timeToHexFunc(thisRandom));
```